# Как отключить сортировку нумераци в начале таблицы?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Нашел как-то http://www.tablesorter.ru/docs/index.php
Сделал все по описанию, но не могу найти, как закрепить нумерацию в начале, то есть при сортировке других столбцов мне нужно, чтобы первый столбец не менялся (нумерация не скакала).   Помогите найти решение.

Comment: Что, никто не знает?

Answer (score 1):

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437290/exclude-a-column-from-being-sorted-using-jquery-tablesorter):

```
$(function() {
    // add new widget called indexFirstColumn
    $.tablesorter.addWidget({
        // give the widget a id
        id: "indexFirstColumn",
        // format is called when the on init and when a sorting has finished
        format: function(table) {               
            // loop all tr elements and set the value for the first column  
            for(var i=0; i < table.tBodies[0].rows.length; i++) {
                $("tbody tr:eq(" + i + ") td:first",table).html(i+1);
            }                                   
        }
    });

    $("table").tablesorter({
        widgets: ['zebra','indexFirstColumn']
    });

});
```